# Why is Django adding "/accounts/logout/" to all {% url %} template tag lookups?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a very simple POC template, in Django, contains this;

```
    <form action="{% url 'formtest' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% url 'formtest' %}

        <input type="submit" value="Vote">

    </form>
```

When I render it, the URL template tags makes my target this;

`/accounts/logout/formtest`

That isn't right, it should be just '/formtest'. And I can't figure out why it's prepending that /accounts/logout bit. The user is not logged in. And my url.py looks like this;

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.index, name='index'),

     path('create_user/<str:username>', views.create_user, name='create_user'),
     path('monitor', views.monitor, name='monitor'),
     path('upload', views.upload_file, name='upload'),
     path('formtest', views.formtest, name='formtest'),

]
```

My Django version is 2.2.5 and I've tried witling down the example to the almost bare minimum. But I can't find why that template tag is adding that bit. I am almost positive something weird or strange has been done by myself, but I failed to find what and where.

Edit: project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('Gallery.urls')),
    path('gallery/', include('Gallery.urls')),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

    path('accounts/profile/', include('Gallery.urls')),
    path('accounts/logout/', include('Gallery.urls')),

 ]
```

Comment: can you share urls.py which is in project there might be the issue

Comment: I that path not working? It's an short version of absolute path, meaning that it just drops the schema and host from the path because it's anyway will point to the host you are runnin now.

Comment: Full urls.py is in there now.

It does "work" I guess, renders the correct page, but the url isn't supposed to look like that right?

Comment: @Eloque the issue is (well, is very likely, at least) in your _project's_ urls.py (not in the app's one).

Comment: You should search in your code for `accounts/logout` or `logout` terms. This may be referenced somewhere it shouldn't. Maybe in your settings.py ?

Comment: Project urls.py in there now as well. That is also where the strings show up indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project urls.py, you have pointed all the base urls to Gallery.urls and since accounts/logout is the last one to resolve, you are getting "/accounts/logout/formtest" for formtest.

There must be only one base url pointing to the Gallery.urls which is this

```
path('gallery/', include('Gallery.urls')),
```

This will resolve formtest to /gallery/formtest". Remove all the other include('Gallery.urls')) lines and point it to the appropriate urls.py files.